# Why can fdisk create a 10GiB partition on a 10GiB device but not a 9.9GiB partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, fdisk, disk-management

I am currently learning about creating and managing devices on my **Ubuntu Server 22.04 VM** running on a **KVM** host. I added a virtual `qcow2` storage disk to the VM. I used `fdisk` and for very specific purposes I need to create a `9.9GiB` partition . I setup a **DOS style partition table** and then tried to create a **primary** partition.

**Following are the steps to reproduce**

```
root@hmxserver:/home/hmx# fdisk /dev/vdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.37.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): o
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xb4942d4d.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): 

Using default response p.
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
First sector (2048-20971519, default 2048): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-20971519, default 20971519): +9.9G
Value out of range.
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-20971519, default 20971519): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 10 GiB.
```

**Questions That I want to ask?**

1. Why is a `10GiB` partition possible but `9.9GiB` is out of range ?
2. I was able accomplish this on **another VM** with similar specs but on **VirtualBox** with a `10GiB` **VMDK** disk attached and repeated the same steps. Why was `fdisk` successful there?
3. Does it have to do with the **qcow2** devices ?
4. Or is it some sort of Floating Point Errors ?

Answer (score 3):

I did a little experimentation, and to me it looks like `fdisk` cannot deal with floating point numbers, so `+9.9G` cannot be parsed while `+9G` or `+10G` can. That means that the error message was wrong.

If all you want is to use all the rest of the disk, simply do not enter a value for the partition end, and use the proposed default instead.

Otherwise, you might have to resort to a smaller unit and enter something like `+10137M` (i.e. `9.9*1024`; remember this is using 1024-based units!).

Alternatively, you could use `parted` or its GUI version `gparted`.